# Sendgrid - Organize Email Templates with Folders

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I have created a few custom email templates on Sendgrid. In order to easily manage them, I want to use folders to group the related templates so that they're not mixed up. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: We just started using Sendgrid and this question came up on Day 1! We're going to be using Sendgrid API as the e-mail gateway for a variety of reports generated from our application. We are going to have dozens, score, possibly hundreds of templates. We are going to need the ability to organize these or this is just not going to scale for us. I see this topic is part of the Twillio collective. Hopefully someone is taking note of this issue.

Comment: Yossi G, have you discovered any way to create folders in SendGrid -- Email Api/Dynamic Templates?